# Convolutional network doesn't give a lower log loss than the class means

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, image-processing

I have tried multiple methods to try to improve the performance of my convolutional neural network  on a multilabel classification problem, but the log loss of the prediction on the test set always seems to stabilize around 0.31.  I have tried image augmentation, different neural net architectures, transfer learning, and hyperparameter tuning.

If I compute the log loss based off of the mean for each label compared to the test set.  As in I compute the means for each class and use the results as the prediction for each test observation, I get a log loss of 0.30.  There are 800 training images and 17 possible labels.

What does this mean and what should I do to improve my results?

The only idea I have left is to try pretraining the conv net on a similar dataset to improve segmentation of the image since there is limited training data, but I have not found a similar dataset. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried XGBoost (or any of the Boosting technique)?

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/deep-learning-xgboost-winning-hands-down-ashish-kumar